# how to stopping the actual for iteration and skip to the next one Python

Tags: python, loops, exception

I am in a for loop with a list and i want to:

1. comeback to a particular part of the loop if I got an exception error, example:

   ```
        try:
            #something
        except NoSuchElementException as exception:
            #come back to a particular point of the loop (past instructions)
   ```
2. i tried the 1) and still got exception, quit from these particular iteration (so i iteration for example) if i got an exception to move to the next item in the list jumping all the rest after.

I thought to use "pass" for 2) but I should do this for every instruction, also "break " doesn't help, do you have any suggestions? thanks

Comment: This looks like very bad design of the program. What kind of program are you trying to write? You should not go back in the code(almost all the time it is bad idea). You can write function, provide one param, that tells you if exception occur and call the function by default with the exception flag to false, and if required call it again. But there is not enough context to provide better solutions. It is just speculation, please make your question more clear what are you doing and provide some example with comments. To skip current loop iteration, call the `continue` like @puffin mention.

Comment: i would like something : if var==True then skip all the next instruction in the loop and go next element in the list

Comment: Ahh so you can use `continue` instruction: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue .

Comment: Yes that was I looking for for the 2) , about the 1) I will try to be more comprensible : im working  on silenium Chrome driver and I'm in a loop that create everyone new chrome session , I want that everytime there is an exception at some point , it will come back to a certain point up to repeat all the operation, yes, I could use functions , but I would to know if there is something other

Comment: Yes There is, but you should never use it(i mean `goto`) :) Those things are called `label` and `goto` http://entrian.com/goto/

Comment: this remind me mips coding , thanks anyway , i will look into!